# Java: How to show odd and even number by using thread and user's input

Tags: java, multithreading, user-input

I and start to using 2 thread, and once for the odd and another one is for the even, but run out the result i get twice the "please input x".
My questions ,how to show the "please input x" only once and still use two thread?

```
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Please input x:");
    x= input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please input y:");
    y=input.nextInt();

    while (x< y) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            while (x % 2 != remainder) { // wait for numbers other than remainder
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + x);
            x++;
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Prompt for and obtain your inputs **ouitside of** (i.e., before starting) the threads.

Comment: it means collect user'input outside the thread,but how to pass in the user'input to run the thread?I try put outside but cannot run the code

Comment: Something, some other code, creates and starts your two threads, yes?

Comment: OK, then.  move the prompts for the `x` and `y` values out from the `run` method (which I'm guessing is in the TaskEvenOdd` class) and Into  `main`, before you create and start your threads.  Modify the `TaskEvenOdd` constructor so that, in addition to the 0 or 1 remainder,  you can also pass in the `x` and `y` values.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
             int y=0;
             int  x=0;
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please input x:");
            x= in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please input y:");
            y=in.nextInt();
            
        }
i put in the main and cannot pass this int to run method ()

Comment: public class TaskEvenOdd implements Runnable {
    public int y=0;
    static int  x=0;
    int remainder;
    static final Object lock=new Object();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // standard constructors
    TaskEvenOdd (int remainder)
    {

        this.remainder=remainder;
    }

    This is my constructor how already modify but still cannot ,where the code wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the general picture of what you need to be doing.

First, modify `TaskEvenOdd` so that you can pass the `x` and `y` values to its constructor and store them in instance variables:

```
public class TaskEvenOdd implements Runnable {
    private int remainder;
    private int x;
    private int y;
  
    public TaskEvenOdd(int remainder, int x, int y){
        this.remainder = remainder;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

    while (x < y) {
        /// etc...
    }
}
```

In main, prompt for the `x` and `y` values, and pass them as arguments to the `OddEvenTask` constructors:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Enter x:");
        int x = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter y:");
        int y = input.nextInt();
        OddEvenTask oddTask = new OddEvenTask(1, x, y);
        OddEvenTask evenTask = new OddEvenTask(0, x, y);
        // Now create and start your threads
    }
```

Comment: In this code and write create thread:
 
Thread t1=new Thread(oddRunnable,"Odd");
            Thread t2=new Thread(evenRunnable,"Even");

            t1.start();
            t2.start();

        }
    }
but run the output only one just the odd or even only and cannot both

Comment: and cannot run two threads they show :::Please input x: 1 Please input y: 9 Odd 1